# SQL insert ID from another table by comparing data from both tables

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a simple question I guess.

I have these 2 tables:

| ID | ARTIST NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bad bunny |
| 3 | Jbalvin |

And

| Song ID | ARTIST NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Bad bunny |
| 101 | Jbalvin |

And I would like to replace the artist name of the second table for the artist ID.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: You can use an inner join along with matching artist_name columns such as t1.artist_name = t2.artist_name

Answer (score 1):

INSERT, REPLACE, etc have **very precise meanings** in SQL because they are commands. In future please use the correct terminology when asking a question.

In this case I will presume you want to substitute ARTIST_ID for ARTIST_NAME; normally this would be an UPDATE. However, using the wrong column (and wrong data type) is bad practice, which will confuse you and any of your co-workers. So you need to change the column name on the target table. There are various ways to acheieve this goal; the one I outline below is the most forgiving on mistakes and exceptions.

So, let's make a foreign key reference between table 1 (`artists`) and table 2 (`songs`). The following example may contain more steps than you require, in which case omit the things you don't want to do.

```
alter table songs add artist_id number
/

-- use MERGE to update one table with values from another

merge into songs song
using (select * from artists) artt
on (artt.artist_name = song.artist_name)
when matched then
  update song.artist_id = artt.artist_id
/

-- this step will fail if you have values of ARTIST_NAME in SONGS 
-- which don't match anything in ARTISTS 

alter table songs 
  modify artist_id not null
/

-- if the last step succeeded, normalise the data model

alter table songs
  drop column artist_name
/
```

Additionally you should add a foreign key (assuming ARTISTS has ARTIST_ID as a primary key...

```
alter table songs
  add constraint song_artt_fk foreign key (artist_id) references artists
/
```